# Doctrine 2 "Class does not exist" on persist

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, one-to-many, many-to-one, persist

So I have these two classes with OneToMany and ManyToOne relationships between them:

```
namespace RM\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @Table(name="users")
 * @Entity
 * @author Csabi
 */
class User {

    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="JobListing", mappedBy="ownerId", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $displayname
     * @Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $displayname;
}
```

and

```
namespace RM\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @Table(name="job_listings")
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="RM\Entity\Repository\JobListingRepository")
 * @author Csabi
 */
class JobListing {

    /**
     * @var integer $id 
     * @Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var User
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User",cascade={"persist"})
     * @JoinColumns({
     *  @JoinColumn(name="ownerId", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * })
     */
    private $ownerId;
```

However, when saving a JobListing, on persist it throws the following error:

```
Application error
Exception information:

Message: Class does not exist
Stack trace:

#0 library\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata.php(67): ReflectionClass->__construct(false)
#1 library\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory.php(350): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata->__construct(false)
#2 library\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory.php(260): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->newClassMetadataInstance(false)
#3 library\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory.php(169): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata(false)
#4 library\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php(247): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor(false)
#5 library\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php(1222): Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getClassMetadata(false)
#6 library\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php(1678): Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->doPersist(1, Array)
#7 library\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php(1252): Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->cascadePersist(Object(RM\Entity\JobListing), Array)
#8 library\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php(1201): Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->doPersist(Object(RM\Entity\JobListing), Array)
#9 library\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php(454): Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->persist(Object(RM\Entity\JobListing))
#10 library\RM\Entity\JobListingService.php(54): Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->persist(Object(RM\Entity\JobListing))
#11 application\controllers\JobListingController.php(28): RM\Entity\JobListingService->saveJobListing(Object(RM\Entity\JobListing))
#12 library\Zend\Controller\Action.php(516): JobListingController->addAction()
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was actually in the object I was trying to save. I did not pass the whole User Entity to the ownerId, only the id of the user.

So when the method

```
Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->doPersist(1, Array)
```

was called it was actually trying to save a number instead of the User Entity.

That is why the error "Class not found" was thrown, because there was no class "1".

Answer (score 1):

You can't define relations on primary keys. Try to add another field in User class:

```
/**
 * @Table(name="users")
 * @Entity
 * @author Csabi
 */
class User {

    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="JobListing", mappedBy="ownerId", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $jobListings;

    /**
     * @var string $displayname
     * @Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $displayname;
}
```

Comment: I did so, but it still gives the same Exception