# Class does not exist Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Ok, so i don't seem to be capable to resolve this on my own...

I'm building an app using symfony and doctrine.

For some reason i need to make calls to my DataBase inside a controller but i've got an error.

Every time i tried to call this function:

```
private function getAgency(string $userid)
    {
        $idAgency=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->find($userid)->getidAgency();
        $Agency=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Agency::class)->find($idAgency);
        return $Agency;
    
    }
```

i've got into this error : `Class App\Entity\Agency does not exist`  witch i don't understand because the Agency Entity definitely exist, the Agency.php file :

```
namespace App\Entity;


use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\AgencyRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity("nameAgency")
 */
class Agency
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="idAgency")
     */
    private $user_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     */
    private $nameAgency;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $idDefaultContact;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $nameContact;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $idContact;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $NameSpecialContact;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $commentary;

    // Contructors

    public function getnameAgency(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nameAgency;
    }

    public function setnameagency(string $nameAgency)
    {
        $this->nameAgency = $nameAgency;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getnameContact(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nameContact;
    }
    public function setnameContact(string $nameContact)
    {
        $this->nameContact = $nameContact;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getcommentary(): ?string
    {
        return $this->commentary;
    }

    public function setcommentary(string $commentary)
    {
        $this->commentary = $commentary;
        return $this;
    }

}
```

As far as i can tell i call the User Entity the same way as the Agency Entity and then i remove the all the Agency calls; the part using the User Entity works perfectly fine...

What i'm missing here?

EDIT: As pointed out; i made use of `use App\Entity\User; use App\Entity\Agency;`

but it doesn't work

Comment: you should use  keywords

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Agency object wherever you call or display

Comment: ```private function getAgency(string $userid)
    {
        $idAgency=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->find($userid)->getidAgency();
        $Agency=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Agency::class)->find($idAgency);
        return $Agency;
    
    } ```

probably there are no  ```use ``` keywords

Comment: Do you mean something like that?
  ``` use App\Entity\User;
use App\Entity\Agency; ```
I definitely make use of use; but it doesn't work either...

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: I encounter the same issue and solved it : the repository didn't have the right use with a wrong path to the entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class does not exist can be caused by 3 differents points:

1. The class itself is wrongly declared (namespace or classname)
2. The call did not use the correct use statement
3. The folder architecture does not match with the declared namespace

As you pointed 1 and 2 seems not to apply in your situation. Can you check 3?

Comment: it might be this effectively....
My Agency.php file is under Entity\InfluenceurManagement\Agency.php and User.php is under Entity\User.php....
How can i keep this folder organisation and make it to work?

Comment: From your src folder, if you have Entity/InfluenceurManagement/Agency.php, then the namespace of Agency.php should be Entity/InfluenceurManagement and for Entity/User.php it should be only Entity

Comment: changing the namespace doesn't seems to have solved my issue but moving the file into the Entity folder (outside of InfluenceurManagement) seems to have solved it

Answer (score 0):

probably missing use keyword

```php
namespace App\Bar;

use App\Entity\Agency;


class Foo
{

private function getAgency(string $userid)
    {
        $idAgency=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->find($userid)->getidAgency();
        $Agency=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Agency::class)->find($idAgency);
        return $Agency;
    
    }
}
```

Comment: no, they are present; doesn't say it in the original post

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847600/doctrine-2-class-does-not-exist-on-persist?rq=1

that link similar to your question may help you

Comment: ok, your link did not help; i tried to find a place where i could miscall my Agency object but could find any...
However the class definitely exist and VS Code detect my getRepository(Agency::class) as a call to this class